# How to do custom sort on multiple tables in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

I want to sort them by these options and doing it one by one for over forty tables is tiring:

```
first, column "Point A": Largest to Smallest
then, column "Point B": Largest to Smallest
then, column "Point C": Largest to Smallest
then, column "Penalties": Smallest to Largest
```

I don't mind doing it one by one per table **if** there's an option to copy these sorting options to make it quicker instead of manually selecting the options for each tables. Also, the tables are spread horizontally so each header doesn't share the same column between the tables.

**Edit for details**

[This is how my table looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ab7l.png)

[And this is the way I want each of the table sorted, as a way to put them in their ranking order based on their result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0nhp.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a quick description of one way to do it.

For this example, one of the tables is at cell D3.

First, record a macro of the sort action. Start macro recorder, sort the table, stop macro recorder.

You will get something like this.

```vb
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
    Range("D3").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("E4:E17") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("F4:F17") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("G4:G17") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("H4:H17") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("D3:H17")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Next, edit the program lines that span multiple lines.

```vb
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
    Range("D3").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("E4:E17"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("F4:F17"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("G4:G17"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("H4:H17"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("D3:H17")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Five of the lines start with `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort` so they can go inside the `With` block.

```vb
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
    Range("D3").Select
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("E4:E17"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("F4:F17"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("G4:G17"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("H4:H17"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SetRange Range("D3:H17")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Next, edit the macro so that all of the ranges are relative to a single cell, D3 in this example.

```vb
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim tmp As Range
    Dim tabl As Range
    
    Set rng = Range("D3")
    Set tmp = Range(rng, rng.End(xlDown))
    Set tabl = Range(tmp, tmp.End(xlToRight))

'   tabl.Select                                 ' this is used during development to make sure that tabl is actually the desired range
    
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        
        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=rng.Offset(0, 1), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=rng.Offset(0, 2), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=rng.Offset(0, 3), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=rng.Offset(0, 4), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    
        .SetRange tabl
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Next, search the internet for a function that searches an Excel sheet for specific cell value.

This is one example.   https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/4/21/find-all-instances-with-vba

Modify the example function to return a range of cells, instead of just highlighting the cells.

Modify the recorded macro to call the "search" function to find all cells containing the text `Player`, which is the top left corner of every table.

Modify the recorded macro to use the returned list of cells from the "search" function and sort the table at each of those cells.

This is what you get.

```vb
Sub sortAll()
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim tmp As Range
    Dim tabl As Range
    Dim allData As Range
    
    Set allData = FindAll("Player")                     ' find all cells containing the text Player
    
    If Not allData Is Nothing Then
        For Each rng In allData                         ' reference the top left corner of each of the tables

            Set tmp = Range(rng, rng.End(xlDown))
            Set tabl = Range(tmp, tmp.End(xlToRight))
        
'           tabl.Select                                 ' only used during development to visually verify that tabl is actually the desired range
            
            With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
                .SortFields.Clear
                
                .SortFields.Add2 Key:=rng.Offset(0, 1), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                .SortFields.Add2 Key:=rng.Offset(0, 2), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                .SortFields.Add2 Key:=rng.Offset(0, 3), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                .SortFields.Add2 Key:=rng.Offset(0, 4), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            
                .SetRange tabl
                .Header = xlYes
                .MatchCase = False
                .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                
                .Apply
            End With
        Next
    Else
        MsgBox "No values were found in this worksheet"
    End If
    
End Sub
'


' PURPOSE: Find all cells containing a specified values
' SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Function FindAll(fnd As String) As Range
    
    Dim FirstFound As String
    Dim FoundCell As Range, rng As Range
    Dim myRange As Range, LastCell As Range
    
    Set myRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
'   myRange.Select                                              ' this is used during development to make sure that myRange is actually the desired range
    
    Set LastCell = myRange.Cells(myRange.Cells.Count)
    Set FoundCell = myRange.Find(what:=fnd, after:=LastCell)
    
    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then                            ' Test to see if anything was found
        FirstFound = FoundCell.Address
    Else
        Set FindAll = Nothing
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    Set rng = FoundCell
    
    
    Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing                               ' Loop until cycled through all unique finds
        Set FoundCell = myRange.FindNext(after:=FoundCell)      ' Find next cell with fnd value
        Set rng = Union(rng, FoundCell)                         ' Add found cell to rng range variable
        If FoundCell.Address = FirstFound Then Exit Do          ' Test to see if cycled through to first found cell
    Loop
    
    Set FindAll = rng                                           ' return range of cells containing find value
End Function
'
```